# a4j:jsFunction actionListener not listening

Tags: java, actionlistener, ajax4jsf

The listener is:

```
public void renderer(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("here=========================");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    setOptimizeActionDTOs(null);
}
```

and `setOptimizeActionDTOs`

```
public void setOptimizeActionDTOs(List<OptimizeActionDTO> optimizeActionDTOs) {
    this.optimizeActionDTOs = optimizeActionDTOs;
}
```

And the a4j:jsFunction is:

```
<a4j:form>          
    <a4j:jsFunction name="renderOptimizeActionList" actionListener="#{rtopHandler.renderer}" oncomplete="renderOptimizeActionList1();"/>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="renderOptimizeActionList1" reRender="profilealertpanel1"></a4j:jsFunction>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        renderOptimizeActionList();
    </script>
</a4j:form>
```

But I can't see any output of the `System.out`. Why? Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `<script>` tags outside the `<form>` tags.
Further, you can check whether the `<a4j:jsFunction>` is called by putting an "***alert()***" on ***onbegin*** event of the `<a4j:jsFunction/>`